# Multi-Label Classification problem with small dataset and multiple labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, multilabel-classification

I am working on a very small dataset (4012 entries) of news headlines, with 148 possible labels. Entries have from 1 to 5 labels associated with them.

Here I am attaching an image of the distribution of number occurrences per subtheme:
[Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SFe2.png)

As you can see the data is highly imbalanced. I have been playing with OneVsRest, Binary Relevance and ML-KNN but I am aware that although I have a high accuracy score, this might be due to the fact that the particular label is not found in test data and thus although it is 100% accurate in not detecting the label, I don't have other instances to test it with.

What is the best approach in this case?

Comment: Not a really an implementation question, hence off-topic here; I recommend you read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info. Then you will know where best to ask:)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use other metrics than accuracy for your multilabel problem. For instance F1 score or precision-recall curve AUC. For instance https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html and https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html.

Also, I recommend you to balance your target labels as well as you can. The easiest way to do that is by dropping samples containing over-represented labels. Since your dataset is so small, and will be even smaller after balancing, I encourage you to create a larger dataset to begin with.

Without more details, I cannot say more. Yet, given a small and very unbalanced dataset, it is generally hard or even impossible to train a solid classifier.